# Cannot find where nunber becomes NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I have a variable that holds the product of multiplication. The two variables that are the factors in this multiplication are numbers that I have verified as `false` with `isNaN()`. One variable is from a `constant` and the other one is from the user `input`.

I've tried using `Number()` and `parseFloat()` on this variable but neither helped.

I have included a `conditional ternary` in the `div` that holds the product so you can see if a number is returned or if the product is not a number.

Can someone tell me where the problem is and how to correct it?

I have replicated the problem in the included snippet.

```js
const space_types = {
  option1: {
    space: 'Option 1',
    kwhuse: 9.4,
    kwhcost: 0.92,
    fueluse: 30.8,
    fuelcost: 0.21,
    othuse: 62.7,
    othcost: 1.17
  }
};

const calculate_utilities = {
  electric: {
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  },
  fuel: {
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  },
  electric1: {
    unit_rate: 0,
    unit_cost: 0,
    unit_usage: 0,
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  },
  fuel1: {
    unit_rate: 0,
    unit_cost: 0,
    unit_usage: 0,
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  }
};

$(function() {
  $("#area").trigger('focus');
  $("#area").blur(function() {
    var type = $("#space_type option:selected").val();
     var area = $("#area").val();
   alert("Is 'area' not a number? (JSFiddle returns FALSE) " + isNaN(area))
    calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost = space_types[type].kwhcost * area;
    calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost = calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost + calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost;
    $("#totals").html(
      isNaN(calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost) ?
      "TRUE: This is not a number" :
      calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  Space Type:
  <select id="space_type" name="space_type">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected value="option1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
  Area:
  <input id="area" type="number" value="100000"> Totals:
  <div id="totals">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost` the digit one is too much ...

Comment: Also, `$("#area").val()` gives you a string, because form fields are _always_ strings. If you know it's a number, convert it with `parseFloat()` (even if it's an integer. Don't use `parseInt` unless you explicit need it parsed as "not a base-10 number", with a radix argument). Also, on a modern JS note: if you're already using `const`, don't use `var`, use `let`. `var` is from the before-days, when we didn't have the block-scoped `const` and `let` yet. And use proper JS conventions for naming. Variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, never lower_snake_case.

Comment: You're assigning to `electric1`, but then checking the value in `electric`.

Comment: Typo: calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost= calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost(`undefined`)+calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost (`number`); -> undefined + number = NaN

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I checked `.val()` and `isNaN()` returned `false`.  10-4 re: naming

Comment: @Valijon - `calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost` and `calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost` are both defined in the `const calculate_utilities`

Comment: @MarkStout `calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost` is **not** defined in calculate_utilities.electric` (no trailing 1) check your code again and see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76644167/6127393

Comment: @Valijon -  You're **right**!  I found the problem!  My original statement was `calculate_utilities.electric.unit_total` = `calculate_utilities.electric.total_cost` + `calculate_utilities.electric1.total_cost`.


It should have been: 
`calculate_utilities.electric.total_cost` = `calculate_utilities.electric.total_cost` + `calculate_utilities.electric1.total_cost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a property in its own definition (adding a defined value with an undefined value results in `NaN`)

```js
calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost = calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost + calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost;
```

Perhaps you have made an error there? Otherwise, you need to initialize that property when you first define `calculate_utilities`

```js
const space_types = {
  option1: {
    space: 'Option 1',
    kwhuse: 9.4,
    kwhcost: 0.92,
    fueluse: 30.8,
    fuelcost: 0.21,
    othuse: 62.7,
    othcost: 1.17
  }
};

const calculate_utilities = {
  electric: {
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0,
    unit_cost: 0
  },
  fuel: {
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  },
  electric1: {
    unit_rate: 0,
    unit_cost: 0,
    unit_usage: 0,
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  },
  fuel1: {
    unit_rate: 0,
    unit_cost: 0,
    unit_usage: 0,
    total_usage: 0,
    total_cost: 0
  }
};

$(function() {
  $("#area").trigger('focus');
  $("#area").blur(function() {
    const type = $("#space_type option:selected").val();
    const area = Number($("#area").val());
    calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost = space_types[type].kwhcost * area;
    calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost = calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost + calculate_utilities.electric1.unit_cost;
    $("#totals").html(
      isNaN(calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost) ?
      "TRUE: This is not a number" :
      calculate_utilities.electric.unit_cost
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  Space Type:
  <select id="space_type" name="space_type">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected value="option1">Option 1</option>
  </select>
  Area:
  <input id="area" type="number" value="100000"> Totals:
  <div id="totals">0</div>
</div>
```